# anyone know of a shared To-do list plugin for eclipse

Tags: eclipse-plugin

Does anyone know of shared TODO list plugin for Eclipse that allows users in a a development team to all view and edit the same list of tasks?

Answer (score 8):

[Mylyn](http://www.eclipse.org/mylyn/) can be used to integrate issue tracking systems into the IDE.

> It does this by making tasks a first class part of Eclipse, and integrating rich and offline editing for repositories such as Bugzilla, Trac, and JIRA.

If you are not looking for a lightweight solution, then you might give it a try.

Answer (score 1):

Other than the already built-in "Tasks"? It works by adding TODO, XXX or FIXME (in caps) in comments in the source code. I think this works pretty good and we use it at work all the time.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know about such particular plug-in, but maybe that you could take a look to what the [Communication framework](http://www.eclipse.org/ecf/) or the [Mylin feature](http://www.eclipse.org/mylyn/) offer you in term of collaborative work.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to track a TODO-list among a couple of developer, you really want to use a issue-tracking system such as Bugzilla, Trac, or Jira. As soon as you've started to add tasks to it, you'll want features such as sorting on different fields, different kinds of views, etc.

That said, Mylyn is the best way to integrate it into Eclipse.

Answer (score 0):

Ive just installed a plugin called [fasttrack](http://www.polarion.org/index.php?page=overview&project=fasttrack) which is just the kind of thing I was looking for. Works best with SVN, but you can also use it with CVS.