# How to create a custom task tag in Eclipse like the TODO or FIXME

Tags: eclipse

How can I make my own custom task tags in eclipse that will show up in my task view?

Is there a way to share this with a team of developers?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

to create a new task tag

```
 windows -> preferences -> search for task tags -> create new tag
```

to share issues with a team you will need to use a third party - see this stackoverflow question for examples

[anyone know of a shared To-do list plugin for eclipse](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/320080/anyone-know-of-a-shared-to-do-list-plugin-for-eclipse)

Comment: thanks! - is there  a way to share this with a team?